# Spark pods in INIT. Reason - FailedMount. Detailed error - MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "trust-store-secret" : failed to sync secret cache:

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

Spark task pods fail to run, stucking in initialization stage for some time, then terminated.

**This issue is not always happening.**

[2022-11-24 20:17:00,367] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -     Could not complete the request. Reason - FailedMount. Detailed error - MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "icp4d-trust-store-secret" : failed to sync secret cache: timed out waiting for the condition

Openshift Container Platform
OCP 4.10
Cloud Platform
IBM Cloud

What could cause this? How to fix it?

Comment: This is a Kubernetes issue. Have you created the `icp4d-trust-store-secret` in K8s? Your spark-submit seems to be expecting it to exist. A similar discussion can be found [here](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/issues/7785)

Comment: Thanks Koedlt for replying. The issue can be reproduced when we repeatedly run the same work load with the same tasks. The most tasks are done successfully. If the secret is not created, then no task can run.